# run command at chef-node by chef management console

Tags: chef-infra

I have successfully installed the chef setup (with server and workstation and node). Now i want to after updating the recipe to server, execute those recipe via management console. just click on a button in the chef server webui and then recipe executes at node machine.

Is there any way to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a feature Chef Server offers. You can rig something up yourself using tools like Chef Push Jobs or RunDeck though.

Comment: well i will link into that. If you could provide any link to follow for Push Jobs that would be great.

Comment: if I upload a cookbook on chef-server it pulled by chef-client, is there any feature available for this.

Comment: Usually people run chef-client as a daemon or cron job do that changes from the Chef Server are picked up automatically on some kind of schedule.